# overflow-y auto; overflow-x; hidden cuts off table

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked before but I can't find a solution that will solve my particular issue.

In this link, the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-box-3/#overflow-x/) spec says:

> The computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’ are the same as their specified values, except that some combinations with ‘visible’ are not possible: if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’. The computed value of ‘overflow’ is equal to the computed value of ‘overflow-x’ if ‘overflow-y’ is the same; otherwise it is the pair of computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’.

I am trying to create a `div` that contains 2 tables.  I want this `div` ( both tables ) to scroll together horizontally and ONLY the bottom grid to scroll vertically.  It seems that by adding `overflow-y`, it automatically creates `overflow-x` set to ‘auto’ and/or when I add overflow-x:hidden my grid gets chopped.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pulmen/cvmewa1d/5/)

```
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

**In summary:**

When scrolling the top(blue) table horizontally, it gives me the desired action but chops off the bottom(red) table.
Vertical scroll of bottom tables works as desired but with missing content.

This [css-tricks link](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/) helps explain my issue with possible 'hacky' solutions using different positions.

How can I stop the bottom table from cutting off my table?  TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `position:sticky;` for toptable container.

Check snippet below:

```css
.toptable-container{
  position:sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top:0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
}

.topTable {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  }

.topTable th {
  min-width: 70px;
}

.topTable td {
  min-width: 70px;
}

.bottomTable {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.bottomTable th {
  min-width: 70px;
}

.bottomTable td {
  min-width: 70px;
  
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}

.bottomTable tr {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 250px; width: 500px; border: 0px solid red; overflow-x: scroll;">
  <div class="toptable-container">
    <table class="topTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <td>
          <img src="http://image.trucktrend.com/f/8488927+w128+h128+re0+cr1+ar0/0804tr-01-ps%2B1951-ford-f1-pickup%2Bleft-side.jpg" height="60">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://image.trucktrend.com/f/39533463+w128+h128+re0+cr1+ar0/1202tr-01%2B1951-ford-f100-the-forgotten-one%2Bside-view.jpg" height="60">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/g_Kibfl6m4TyprRD5HQSy9qMPXqfUNvE-g3jmb_GPshEydWyNSYyDWEp6ViAovomc_B9F3kJBQ=w128-h128-n-no-v1" height="60">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://image.trucktrend.com/f/70429704+w128+h128+re0+cr1+ar0/1951-chevrolet-3100-front-three-quarters.jpg" height="60"></td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://image.trucktrend.com/f/100935933+w128+h128+re0+cr1+ar0/024-1960-ford-f-100-caterpillar-diesel-engine-swap-rat-rod-pickup-patina-paint-job-side-view.jpg" height="60"></td>
        <td>
          <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/g_Kibfl6m4TyprRD5HQSy9qMPXqfUNvE-g3jmb_GPshEydWyNSYyDWEp6ViAovomc_B9F3kJBQ=w128-h128-n-no-v1" height="60"></td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://image.trucktrend.com/f/8488927+w128+h128+re0+cr1+ar0/0804tr-01-ps%2B1951-ford-f1-pickup%2Bleft-side.jpg" height="60">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://image.trucktrend.com/f/100935933+w128+h128+re0+cr1+ar0/024-1960-ford-f-100-caterpillar-diesel-engine-swap-rat-rod-pickup-patina-paint-job-side-view.jpg" height="60"></td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://image.trucktrend.com/f/70429704+w128+h128+re0+cr1+ar0/1951-chevrolet-3100-front-three-quarters.jpg" height="60">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="">
    <table class="bottomTable" style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; position: relative; height: 150px;">
      <tr>
        <th>
          Year
        </th>
        <td>1949</td>
        <td>1950</td>
        <td>1951</td>
        <td>1951</td>
        <td>1955</td>
        <td>1951</td>
        <td>1949</td>
        <td>1955</td>
        <td>1951</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Color
        </th>
        <td>Black</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td>Yellow</td>
        <td>Silver</td>
        <td>Patina</td>
        <td>Yellow</td>
        <td>Black</td>
        <td>Patina</td>
        <td>Silver</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Trans
        </th>
        <td>Auto</td>
        <td>Auto</td>
        <td>Manual</td>
        <td>Auto</td>
        <td>Manual</td>
        <td>Manual</td>
        <td>Auto</td>
        <td>Manual</td>
        <td>Auto</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Wheel
        </th>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>
          Bed length
        </th>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>     
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/cfq9voju/)

Answer (score 0):

starting with the wrapper of the top and bottom parts:

```
element.style {
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 0px solid red;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

- it has fixed width and height
- its overflow-x is set to scroll
- therefore its overflow-y is automatically set to auto

inside it there are two child divs.

- first one has no rules set, so it goes on while its restricted parent scrolls after 500px
- second one has no set width, it inherits the width of its parent as a block, and considers anything after the inherited 500px to be hidden according to the overflow rule you set

**the solution**

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
.container1 {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.topTable th {
  min-width: 70px;
}

.topTable td {
  min-width: 70px;
}

.bottomTable {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.bottomTable th {
  min-width: 70px;
}

.bottomTable td {
  min-width: 70px;
  
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}

.bottomTable tr {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="overflow-x: scroll;">
  <div class="container1">
    <table class="topTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <td>
          <img src="http://image.trucktrend.com/f/8488927+w128+h128+re0+cr1+ar0/0804tr-01-ps%2B1951-ford-f1-pickup%2Bleft-side.jpg" height="60">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://image.trucktrend.com/f/39533463+w128+h128+re0+cr1+ar0/1202tr-01%2B1951-ford-f100-the-forgotten-one%2Bside-view.jpg" height="60">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/g_Kibfl6m4TyprRD5HQSy9qMPXqfUNvE-g3jmb_GPshEydWyNSYyDWEp6ViAovomc_B9F3kJBQ=w128-h128-n-no-v1" height="60">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://image.trucktrend.com/f/70429704+w128+h128+re0+cr1+ar0/1951-chevrolet-3100-front-three-quarters.jpg" height="60"></td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://image.trucktrend.com/f/100935933+w128+h128+re0+cr1+ar0/024-1960-ford-f-100-caterpillar-diesel-engine-swap-rat-rod-pickup-patina-paint-job-side-view.jpg" height="60"></td>
        <td>
          <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/g_Kibfl6m4TyprRD5HQSy9qMPXqfUNvE-g3jmb_GPshEydWyNSYyDWEp6ViAovomc_B9F3kJBQ=w128-h128-n-no-v1" height="60"></td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://image.trucktrend.com/f/8488927+w128+h128+re0+cr1+ar0/0804tr-01-ps%2B1951-ford-f1-pickup%2Bleft-side.jpg" height="60">
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="http://image.trucktrend.com/f/100935933+w128+h128+re0+cr1+ar0/024-1960-ford-f-100-caterpillar-diesel-engine-swap-rat-rod-pickup-patina-paint-job-side-view.jpg" height="60"></td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://image.trucktrend.com/f/70429704+w128+h128+re0+cr1+ar0/1951-chevrolet-3100-front-three-quarters.jpg" height="60">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <table class="bottomTable">
      <tr>
        <th>
          Year
        </th>
        <td>1949</td>
        <td>1950</td>
        <td>1951</td>
        <td>1951</td>
        <td>1955</td>
        <td>1951</td>
        <td>1949</td>
        <td>1955</td>
        <td>1951</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Color
        </th>
        <td>Black</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td>Yellow</td>
        <td>Silver</td>
        <td>Patina</td>
        <td>Yellow</td>
        <td>Black</td>
        <td>Patina</td>
        <td>Silver</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Trans
        </th>
        <td>Auto</td>
        <td>Auto</td>
        <td>Manual</td>
        <td>Auto</td>
        <td>Manual</td>
        <td>Manual</td>
        <td>Auto</td>
        <td>Manual</td>
        <td>Auto</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Wheel
        </th>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <th>
          Bed length
        </th>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>     
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

the position sticky is the way to go for the design you're looking for